# Extremely Simple ng-show animation with AngularJS

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I do not want an HTML element to pop up without any kind of transition or animation, I'm trying to understand exactly how the AngularJS ngAnimate directive works:

Here's the HTML I would like to appear with an animation:

```
    <a ng-show="county_global_var != undefined" class="list-group-item media region_flag_california">

  <div class="media-body">      

        <div ng-show="current_political == 'administrative_area_level_2'">
        <h5 style="opacity:0.65;"><span id="default_region" class="label label-primary">{$ county_global_var $}</span></h5>

          <span>
            <h6><span class="label label-success">NOW IN CHAT</span></h6>
          </span>         

        </div>   

        <div ng-show="current_political != 'administrative_area_level_2'">
        <h5><span id="default_region" class="label label-primary">{$ county_global_var $}</span></h5>

          <span>
            <h6><span class="label label-default keep-in-front">TAP TO JOIN</span></h6>
          </span>              
        </div>                


  </div>

  <div style="" ></div>
</a>
```

I've already added the 'ngAnimate' to my "angular.module" and the animate library is imported as in Django:

```
<script src="{% static "bootstrap/js/angular-animate.min.js" %}"></script>
```

This is the CSS code:

```
.list-group-item.media.region_flag_california.ng-show
{
    -webkit-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -moz-transition:0.5s linear all;
    -o-transition:0.5s linear all;
    transition:0.5s linear all;
    opacity:1;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
    height:90px;
    background-position:center; 
}
```

And so the CSS aspect is where I'm clueless, I have no idea how to treat the CSS code. The CSS code above has .ng-show added which is not being applied to the anchor tag with the matching class and which also has an ng-show effect.

How can I make it so the css initially has an opacity of 0 until the ng-show is triggered?

Also, what's the best analogy for how Angular animate works? Does each CSS for `.list-group-item.media.region_flag_california` contain a specific state? such as begining, middle, and end? Kind of like how a video contains frames which show one after the other?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of newer libraries that you can use to assist with animations.

1. [NG-FX](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ng-Fx) - These are javascript based animations
2. [ngAnimate.css](http://theoinglis.github.io/ngAnimate.css/#/) - These are CSS based animations

Another option is to just use [Animate.css](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/25/easy-animations-for-angularjs-with-animate-css.aspx) (which is what I've typically done in the past). But that requires you to understand what classes are being applied during a show/hide process. You are correct in assuming that there are various states.

OdeToCode.com has an example of [using Angular with Animate.css](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/02/25/easy-animations-for-angularjs-with-animate-css.aspx). And he explains the process pretty quickly.

Another explanation (just came across this one): [Moving with Angular 1.2 Animation and Animate.css](http://www.divshot.com/blog/tips-and-tricks/angular-1-2-and-animate-css/)
Otherwise, if you want a more in depth look at how `ngAnimate` works, jessicaspacekat has some good slides on how to [design css transitions using angularjs](https://speakerdeck.com/jessicaspacekat/an-introduction-to-designing-css-transitions-using-angularjs?utm_source=ng-newsletter&utm_campaign=c56ef09e3f-AngularJS_Newsletter_4_28_144_28_2014&utm_medium=email&utm_term=0_fa61364f13-c56ef09e3f-87733445).

This image is taken from her slides (slide 64 of 94)
[image: ngShow Animation Cheatsheet]